# Visual Studio Code: Breakpoint placed in function on Call Stack for another Breakpoint Isn't triggered?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm using VSCode to debug a Linux program (https://github.com/XCSoar/XCSoar).  When I click on a particular button in the program display, I hit a breakpoint placed in a particular function (EditDataFieldDialog()).  With the program stopped, VSCode displays the call stack for that function, as shown in the following photo (couldn't use screengrab, as the mouse is still captured by the application being debugged):

[image]

The right-hand side of the image shows the program stopped at EditDataFieldDialog(), and the left-hand side shows this is also the top of the call stack, as expected.  Looking further back in the stack, I saw two other program functions 'OnEditTurnpointClicked()' and 'EditTaskPoint' (shown highlighted in red).  However, when I placed breakpoints in these functions, neither were hit.

I thought anything in the application under debug that showed up in the call stack was by definition a valid breakpoint target - am I missing something here?

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean neither red breakpoint was hit from the start of program execution, or from the time right before you clicked.  From your callstack, it looks like somewhere between the areas you marked in yellow and red, there is an event loop running for a modal dialog.  Thus I think that before you click, you are already inside the functions marked in red.

Comment: I meant that a breakpoint at either of the 'red' functions was never hit.  Unfortunately, when I tried this same trick this morning, breakpoints in either 'red' function successfully broke program flow - go figure